# Get current postion from videoview in Time format

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am writing an application to trim videos in android using `FFMPEG`. I need to give the values to the `FFMPEG` in time units like `00:00:10`. Currently I have a `videoview` and two `buttons`. The first button is `startTime` and the second button is `endTime`. When ever the button is clicked I use the `getCurrentPosition` to get the current position of the video. I also have a `MediaController` attached to my `videoview`.

Now the problem I am facing is that I get `int` value of the current position which I cannot pass to the `FFMPEG` how do I accurately convert this to get the value in Time units, so that I can pass it to `FFMPEG` to trim the video. I have given the code below for your reference. Is there any other way to get the current time other than this. Thanks in advance.

```
        tVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.tVideoView);
        startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tStartBtn);
        endBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tEndBtn);
        trimBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trimBtn);

        tVideoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);
        duration = tVideoView.getDuration();
        mMedia = new MediaController(this);

        mMedia.setMediaPlayer(tVideoView);
        mMedia.setAnchorView(tVideoView);
        tVideoView.setMediaController(mMedia);

        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startTime = tVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
                startBtn.setText(String.valueOf(startTime));
            }
        });

        endBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                endTime = tVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
                endBtn.setText(String.valueOf(endTime));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Function to convert milliseconds to time format

```
String getVideoTime(long ms)
{
    ms/=1000;
    return (ms/3600)+":"+((ms%3600)/60)+":"+((ms%3600)%60);
}
```

And call it in your runnable or timer to update UI

```
String tm = getVideoTime(
    videoView.getCurrentPosition()) + 
    " / " +
    getVideoTimeFormat(videoView.getCurrentPosition()
);
tvVideoTime.setText(tm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple method to get the milliseconds time in a Date format,

```
/**
 * Return date in specified format.
 * @param milliSeconds Date in milliseconds
 * @param dateFormat Date format 
 * @return String representing date in specified format
 */
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
{
    // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

    // Create a calendar object that will convert the time value in milliseconds to date. 
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
     return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

To call the method,

```
String time = (getDate(12184, "hh:mm:ss"));
```

This will return a standard time format like, `06:00:12`